# Alternative layout for tabPanel?

Tags: visualforce

The `<apex:tabPanel>` element displays with a row of horizontal tabs, like so:

[image: Sample tabPanel from Salesforce.com docs]

Is there a way to indicate an alternative layout, such as a column of tab buttons with the content to the side?

(I know it's possible to make stylistic changes by using `styleClass` and css, but since tabPanels are (by default) rendered in a whole mess of `<table>` tags, I can't figure out a way to rearrange the underlying elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you don't have many options with your  tag, however, nothing stops you from writing HTML/CSS/Javascript yourself in Visualforce and making the layout you want, however some web development knowledge is required to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to the top of your Visualforce page: `<apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/21.0/sprites/1297816277000/Theme3/default/gc/versioning.css" />`

Comment: Can you explain how an why this would work?